# Angular-chart not updating chart real-time when using timer

Tags: angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart

I started experimenting with angular-chart.js on angularjs.

I was able to render a chart from initial data, but when i change the data using a timer the chart doesn't update real time.

the originial chart.js library has a chart.update() function which updates the chart, i cant seem to find something of that sort in angularjs.

This is what i have so far

**Controller**

```
$scope.value1 = 87;
$scope.value2 = 25;

$scope.pie2_labels = ["Total Staff", "Available Labor Pool"];
$scope.pie2_data = [$scope.value1,$scope.value2];

setInterval(function(){ $scope.value2 = $scope.value2 + 1;
$scope.pie2_data = [$scope.value1, $scope.value2];
});

$scope.pie2_colors = [{backgroundColor:"rgba(255,99,132,1)",pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)"},{backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.2)"}];
$scope.pie2_options = { global: { responsive: true }, legend: { display: true, position: 'top' }, title: {display: true, text: 'Staffing'} };
```

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="pie2" class="chart chart-pie" chart-data="pie2_data" chart-labels="pie2_labels" chart-colors="pie2_colors" chart-options="pie2_options" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

I assumed angular's two way binding automatically updates the chart which it isn't doing. i see updated values on console.log but no change in the graph.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use `setInterval` because the Angular digest cycle is not aware of it. Instead use [`$interval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval).

Comment: that worked, thanks Lex. Learnt something new today.